# LWC Lightning-input-field not showing lookup correctly

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

I have a LWC where I am using `lightning-input-field` to display a custom field on custom object which is a look up to other object, it doesn't display correctly.

Here's the code :

```
<lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
    <div style="padding-bottom: 21px;"></div>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Venue__c" required>
    </lightning-input-field>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

Here's how it looks when I click on the field, the suggestions are not shown until the user types something,
[image]

I am using `lightning-record-edit-form`, otherwise I would use a custom lookup and pass on values. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: i think you have faced same issue like https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349125&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1 this, did you try to add pagelayout?

Comment: yes It is already on page layout, I research a few other articles too but couldn't get it to work unless I use a custom lookup.

Comment: to clarify, you're expecting recently viewed `venues` to display when you click on the lookup? I have no issue seeing that behavior with the code you provided. If you go to the `Recently Viewed` Venues list view, do you see any records?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I did not. Only option is to develop a custom lookup which will mess up a lot of standard functionality.